# regular expression for integer and floating number

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to validate the integer number and float number from `0` to `5.0` not more than `5` The regex should be invalid for negative number.
I have tried this

```
  ^(\-|\+)?([0-5]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$
```

but it is applicable for all the integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-4](?:\.\d)?$|5(?:\.0)?$
```

this will help you

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/uP4lM5